# Typescript and CSS : Align label with the checkbox

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, vertical-alignment

I am working on a project where there is a checkbox and a label, and they need to be aligned on the same line, with the text vertically aligned center to the checkbox. But the text comes slightly below the checkbox.

```
import React from "react";

import './checkbox.less';

interface ICheckBoxProps {
  label: string;
}

const Checkbox:React.FC<ICheckBoxProps> = ({label}) => (
    <div className="flex">
      <div>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          id={label}
          className = "container"
        />     
        <label htmlFor={label} className="label">{label}</label> 
      </div>
    </div>
  )
export default Checkbox;
```

The CSS File :

```
.App {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    position:relative;
    display: inline;
  }


.container {
    margin-bottom: 12px;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 22px;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align:middle;
    display:inline-block;
    }

  
.flex{
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: flex-start;
vertical-align:middle;
display: inline-flex;
}

.label{
    display : inline;
}
```

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you apply a `margin-bottom: 12px;` on your `<input type="checkbox"/>` element (through `.container` class):

```
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          id={label}
          className = "container"
        />
```

```css
.container {
    margin-bottom: 12px;
```

You can simply not apply this margin on the `<input>` only (see label1 in below screenshot), or apply it on the containing div (that wraps both the `<input>` and the `<label>`, see label2 in below screenshot):

[image: result]

```
  <div className="flex">
    <div class="container2">
      <input type="checkbox" id="label2" class="container1" />
      <label for="label2" class="label">{label2 margin-bottom on containing div (both input and label)}</label>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```css
.container1 {
  /*margin-bottom: 12px;*/
}

.container2 {
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/sabr7xw0/2/